# What is use if Itemid() in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

I m new In joomla 1.5 and I m Using a itemid on read more link but do not understand the use of itemid and because if it use for display article in menulink vise than i have 4 menu and still i am writing a article&id=14 & itemid=5 still show a article.even though i have only 4 menu,

```
how it show my article on another page it should be error
```

Answer (score 1):

itemid is id of menu. So its basically menuid. You can go to joomla table and see the table jos_menu the id field there is itemid. Menu can be associated with several things.Like compoents external links etc. When you access a menu it is getting its itemid to seperate it from another menu.

Comment: Because it's the menu ID, it is also the key factor when deciding if something is visible to Visitors, Registered Users, or Admins.